# Как сделать показывалась изображения с определенной частотой. например с частотой в 60% случаях

Tags: php

Как сделать  показывалась изображения с определенной частотой. например  с частотой в 60% случаях.

Comment: `if( rand(0,100) < 60 ) { show_image(); }` - вы про это?

Comment: @PinkTux но тут не 60% случаев, я могу сто раз обновить страницу и картинку увидеть,  а могу не разу не увидеть. Хотя коментарий хорош.

Comment: @Naumov, OK, с вероятностью 60% :) Требуется уточнение. 60 первых раз из ста, гарантированно 60 раз из ста со случайным разбросом? Тогда надо заводить внешние счётчики загрузок страницы/показов картинки и отслеживать их.

Answer (score 1):

Вам по любому надо где то записывать  сколько раз показалось `$view` из числа всех вызовов `$all`.

```
if ($view/$all >= 0.6 ) { не показывать }
```